# Pasting unique identifiers together issue

Tags: r

I am studying stocks of fish in the open ocean caught by fisherman. Recently I have begun to measure distance between individual fish with known stocks and evaluate if the stocks (>15 unique stocks) travel together.

My issue is that I when I am comparing stocks I paste() the stock names together and sometimes the pasted together ids will be stock.1_stock.2 or other times it will be stock.2_stock.1. I need them to have the same unique identifier, but I do not know how best to approach this problem in R. Does anyone have any suggestions?

My actual data frame is large (>100,000 rows), which may affect how you answer the question.

Here is some code to generate a smaller example data set:

```
#making generic ids
ids <- rep("stock",times=3)
ids <- paste(ids,1:3, sep=".")

#making simple example
tmp <- expand.grid(ids,ids)
tmp <- tmp[ifelse(tmp$Var1==tmp$Var2,T,F)==F,]
tmp$dist <- c(1,2,1,4,2,4)

#comparing stocks
tmp$both <- paste(tmp$Var1,tmp$Var2, sep="_")
tmp
#      Var1    Var2 dist            both
# 2 stock.2 stock.1    1 stock.2_stock.1
# 3 stock.3 stock.1    2 stock.3_stock.1
# 4 stock.1 stock.2    1 stock.1_stock.2
# 6 stock.3 stock.2    4 stock.3_stock.2
# 7 stock.1 stock.3    2 stock.1_stock.3
# 8 stock.2 stock.3    4 stock.2_stock.3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you sort the pair of ids for each row you will end up with a unique combined id for each pairing:

```
tmp$both <- paste(pmin(as.character(tmp$Var1), as.character(tmp$Var2)),
                  pmax(as.character(tmp$Var1), as.character(tmp$Var2)), sep="_")
tmp
#      Var1    Var2 dist            both
# 2 stock.2 stock.1    1 stock.1_stock.2
# 3 stock.3 stock.1    2 stock.1_stock.3
# 4 stock.1 stock.2    1 stock.1_stock.2
# 6 stock.3 stock.2    4 stock.2_stock.3
# 7 stock.1 stock.3    2 stock.1_stock.3
# 8 stock.2 stock.3    4 stock.2_stock.3
```